# What would male concubines be called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m asking this with a “concubine” being a woman, or one in a group of women, that one man considers routine sexual partners, with no intention of assuming marriage or a romantic role beyond what might be necessary to keep each woman happy. These women are not necessarily aware of each other; they constitute a “stable” of routine sexual partners.

Is there an equivalent term for a man, or group of men, who are in a relationship with a woman that routinely has sexual encounters with them under similar circumstances? I’m looking for a word that would describe a man who functions as such a concubine, whether he’s aware of it or not.

Comment: "Consort" might be too strongly associated with royalty, but it is applicable to men as well as women.

Comment: I don't think there is/was a male equivalent. A concubine was a woman who slept with a high-status man on an 'official' basis, but was of lower status than his wife/wives. For reasons of biology and gender politics, it never happened the other way round.

Comment: @KateBunting according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Chatterley%27s_Lover) Lawrence's fiction about Lady Chatterley was inspired by real events. Or is the difference that the situation you describe was endorsed: was no secret?

Comment: Called by whom? In what language?

Comment: For a group of men, *a stable.* See AHD for the use of *stable* to refer to all the horses owned by one person or organization, or all the athletes under common management.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I didn't say that married women never took lovers, just that _concubine_ doesn't normally refer to a secret adulterous affair. It was a semi-official arrangement in societies that recognised such relationships.

Comment: [Gigolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigolo) is probably the nearest thing; it can refer to a kept man but doesn't have the concept of a group of men.

Comment: A reasonably common expression is "a [kept man](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kept%20man)." It adds a connotation, though, that the man is financially supported by his lover.

Answer (score 4):

I've always heard a phrase used for this: *male concubine*. (It is, in fact, such a natural term for this that it's used in the question itself.)

Here are some examples:

> The rise and fall of Emperor Qian's male concubine — [South China Morning Post](https://www.scmp.com/article/318417/rise-and-fall-emperor-qians-male-concubine)

> Women were forbidden from taking a male concubine. — [Wikipedia: Islamic views on concubinage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_views_on_concubinage)

You may also be able to borrow a term from another culture, if that's what's being discussed. For example, when discussing the Romans:

> [M]any well-off Roman men kept a male concubine called concubinus — [The Evolution of Same-Sex Attraction](https://books.google.com/books?id=R4oBEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&dq=%22male%20concubine%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU9JDa45j0AhUYpnIEHe3AA4E4FBDoAXoECAoQAg)

Finally, when talking about a modern-day relationship, there are more words available. (But the word *concubine* wouldn't be used here, not for a woman or man.) The term that comes to my mind is side-piece, which although being most commonly applied to "the other woman" can also be used for a man:

> A side piece in an affair is not gender specific. Hollywood has portrayed the side piece to be a woman or a victim of the "situationship", imposing double standards. Typically, cheating is associated with men, and the language used to describe it include jump off, side piece, and mistress, which refer to men sleeping with multiple women. Yet we don’t talk about women doing the cheating, or women having a man as their side piece. — [Medical Daily](https://www.medicaldaily.com/psychology-behind-being-side-piece-affair-420706)

Answer (score 2):

If it's a monarch or other important person - I don't think regular people get to have concubines - "Favourite" is often used. James I had "favourites" who were always attractive young men, and Potemkin is often described as Catherine the Great's most famous "favourite".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favourite

Answer (score 1):

Concubine is interchangeable. Given the *-one* suffix would denote a male and *concubone* is not a word, concubine serves for both sexes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think 'concubone' creates entirely the wrong picture in the mind's eye.

Comment: You could add a reference to the Etymonline account of the word.  It confirms exactly what you sat.  The Latin root has the stem "concubin-", of which the masculine form is 'concubinus' snd the feminine is 'concubina'.  As it happens, English adjectives do not inflect by gender.  So there is no semantic or grammatical reason why 'concubine should not apply to male as well as female. Of course, historically, there have only been female ones.  the same is true of 'prostitue' so that we speak of a 'male prostitute'  On that precedent use 'male concubine'

Comment: In the Bible, concubines were baby makers, not low-value toys or high-value spouses. See Hagar and Abraham. Not easily male.

Answer (score 1):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/concubine) sheds some light as to the etymology of '*concubine*':

> *Middle English: from Old French, from Latin* concubina, *from con- ‘with’ + cubare ‘to lie’.*

The nominative singular noun, *concubina*, with the suffix -a, implies a feminine form (see also [here](https://definify.com/word/-a?q=-a)), and the male equivalent would be **concubinus** (also '*bridegroom*'), which is corroborated by [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/concubine).

The fact we only have a single word is arguably more of a testimony to our hetero-normative and androcentric history than to the origin of the word.

A short but more nuanced article on the usage of both terms can be found [here](http://emilykq.weebly.com/blog/concubinus-male-concubines-in-the-roman-empire).